# Comparison values stored in different json db (node red)

Tags: json, node.js, database, node-red

working with NodeRed...

I have stored my sensor values (msg.payload.data) into a json db DataIn and I want to compare them with some reference values (msg.payload.ref) stored in an other db DataIn.

```
if(msg.payload.data==msg.payload.ref)
...
```

seems not to work unfortunately.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "seems not to work"? Do you get any error? Do you get the result that you don't expect? What _do_ you expect?

Comment: I mean that i don't get the expected result. Now I solved, msg.payload.data was saved as a string instead I had a number in msg.payload.ref